# Error while creating simple table

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't see why this fails :o

```
CREATE TABLE "Permission" (
"id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("id") 
);
```

The message

```
Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"Permission" (
"id" INT NOT NULL,
"name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("id' at line 1
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong quoting character.  You should use ` marks not " marks for table names and columns.

```
 CREATE TABLE `Permission` (
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, 
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)  
 );
```

Comment: Thank you it works! (site does not let me accept the answer yet until 6 minutes pass). Funny thing is this code was generated by a visual design tool :(

Comment: Visual design tools can be great for high level, but it's always worth eyeballing the SQL by hand before running it; some of them spit out some goofy SQL now and then.

Comment: The visual design tool is likely expecting that the MySQL session will have `SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES'`, which then permits the use of double quotes around object references.

Answer (score 1):

quickshiftin's answer is good.
And you should also change:

```
`id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
```

to:

```
`id` INT NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL normally uses the backtick character to enclose object references, as quickshiftin's answer says.

But it's not really "wrong" to use double quotes, it's just that the MySQL default behavior is to not permit double quotes to be used in that way.

It is possible to have MySQL allow the double quote character to be used around object references by enabling the `ANSI_QUOTES` sql mode for your session. I would recommend you do this only temporarily, just to get your tables defined, and then set it back.

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'

SET sql_mode = 'ANSI_QUOTES'
```

Before you set the sql_mode variable, you want to note the current setting, so you can set it back after you have your tables created.

```
SET sql_mode = ''
```

It's also possible to set this variable at the database level, but I've never seen that done before. I've only ever (temporarily) overridden the default at the session level, for importing SQL table definitions that use double quotes.